# Need help Write a program using flowchart/ python that computes for the average of scores of a student. Scores accepted must be between 0 to 100

Tags: python

This is the code I currently have in Python via Flowchart

**TASK**
Write a program using flowchart (or python, c++) that computes for the average of scores of a student. Scores accepted must be between 0 to 100.

Sample console:

Enter test scores from 0 to 100.

To end the program, enter -1.

```
Enter score: 90
Enter score: 80
Enter score: 150
Score must be from 0 to 100. Try again.
Enter score: 75
Enter score: -1

Score count: 3
Score total: 245

Average score: 81.6667
```

**My code:**

```
print("Enter score: ")
score = int(input())
scoreCount = 3
while score >= 0 and score <= 100:
    print("Enter score: ")
    score = int(input())
    if score > 100:
        print("Score must be from 0 to 100. Try again.")
        score = int(input())
    else:
        if score < 0:
            print("Score count: ", end='', flush=True)
            print(scoreCount)
            print("Score total: ", end='', flush=True)
            print(scoreTotal)
            print("Average: ", end='', flush=True)
            print(avgScore, end='', flush=True)
        else:
            scoreTotal = score + score + score
    avgScore = float(scoreTotal) / scoreCount
```

I need help, the average doesn't add up to 245, I think the placement of my code is causing the issue...

I expect when entering these:

```
Enter test scores from 0 to 100.

To end the program, enter -1.

 
START
Enter score: 90
Enter score: 80
Enter score: 150
Score must be from 0 to 100. Try again.
Enter score: 75
Enter score: -1

Score count: 3
Score total: 245

Average score: 81.6667
END
```

that my code would produce the same outputs.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few errors with the code in the question:

- checking for < 0 twice (not necessary)
- scoreTotal = score + score + score (does not make sense)

what is required:

- increment score.
- increment a counter.

The arrangement would look like this:

```py
n = 0
total_score = 0
for i in range(100):
    score = input('enter score (q to quit): ')
    if score == 'q':
        break
    
    score = int(score)

    if 0 < score < 100:
        total_score += score
        n = n + 1
        average_score = total_score / n
        print(n, 'current average:', average_score)
    else:
        print('score must be between 0 and 100')
    
    
if n == 0:
    average_score = 'no score'

print('final average score:', round(average_score, 2))
```

result:

```
1 current average: 25.0
2 current average: 37.5
3 current average: 50.0
score must be between 0 and 100
4 current average: 50.0
5 current average: 50.0
6 current average: 52.5
final average score: 52.5
```